# How to retrieve an Oracle directory path?

Tags: oracle, directory

I created the following Oracle Directory `csvDir`:

```
create or replace directory csvDir as
 'd:\oracle\oradata\external_data\downloadedFiles';
```

Now, how can I retrieve the path from this `csvDir` alias?

There should be some system table that stores this path.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That would be the ALL_DIRECTORIES view:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1075.htm#i1576965

Comment: Thanks! ALL_DIRECTORIES works for all roles, so I don't need to mess with privileges.
`select directory_path from all_directories where upper(directory_name) = 'CSVDIR'` works fine

Answer (score 18):

```
select directory_path from dba_directories where upper(directory_name) = 'CSVDIR'
```

Answer (score 9):

The ALL_DIRECTORIES data dictionary view will have information about all the directories that you have access to. That includes the operating system path

```
SELECT owner, directory_name, directory_path
  FROM all_directories
```